# SQL Server: Select and count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables:

```
> HockeyTeam with columns: ID and Name 
> HockeyGame with columns: ID,Team1ID and Team2ID (both linked to HockeyTeam ID) 
> GameScores with columns: ID, GameID, Team1Score, Team2Score
```

**HockeyTeam**

```
ID   Name
1    Monkeys
2    Beavers
3    Dolphins
4    Snakes
```

**GameScore**

```
ID   GameID   Team1Score   Team2Score
1    1        3            2
2    2        4            0
3    3        2            3
4    4        2            4
```

**HockeyGame**

```
ID   StartTime   Team1ID   Team2ID
1    2/6/2015    1         2
2    2/13/2015   3         4
3    2/20/2015   2         4
4    2/27/2015   1         3
```

I need to display total goals for each team. A team can be in both `Team1ID` or `Team2ID`. Here is what I got so far:

```
SELECT  
    ht.Name, 
    SUM(SELECT (gs.Team1Score + gs.Team2Score) 
        FROM GameScores as gs
            INNER JOIN HockeyGame as hg
            INNER JOIN  HockeyTeam  as ht
            ON ht.ID = hg.Team1ID OR ht.ID = ht.Team2ID
            ON gs.GameID = hg.ID
FROM 
    HockeyTeam  as ht
```

Comment: In addition to what you've posted, we need to see sample data and the output you want to obtain from that data.

Comment: the question is Display total goals for each team

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's take a structure like this below:

```
create table team (id int, name varchar(20));
insert into team values (1, 'H1'), (2, 'H2'), (3, 'H3');

create table game (id int, team1id int, team2id int);
insert into game values (11, 1, 2), (12, 1, 3), (13, 2, 3);

create table score (
  id int,
  gameid int,
  team1score int,
  team2score int
);
insert into score values 
(21, 11, 5, 2), 
(22, 12, 2, 5), 
(23, 13, 0, 2);
```

**Display game results (not the answer yet)**

```
-- show readable game results
select
  s.gameid,
  t1.name as team1,
  t2.name as team2,
  team1score,
  team2score
from score s
inner join game g on s.gameid = g.id
inner join team t1 on g.team1id = t1.id
inner join team t2 on g.team2id = t2.id;
```

Data looks like this:

```
gameid  team1  team2  team1score  team2score
11      H1     H2     5           2
12      H1     H3     2           5
13      H2     H3     0           2
```

**Let's get the scores now (the answer)**

```
-- show score by team 
select
  t.name,
  sum(score) as goals
from team t

left join 
(
  -- get score of team1
  select
    t1.id as teamid,
    sum(team1score) as score
  from score s
  inner join game g on s.gameid = g.id
  inner join team t1 on g.team1id = t1.id
  group by t1.id

  union all

  -- get score of team2 and combine it with results from team1
  -- this is because team2 can be team1 for some games
  select
    t2.id as teamid,
    sum(team2score) as score
  from score s
  inner join game g on s.gameid = g.id
  inner join team t2 on g.team2id = t2.id
  group by t2.id
) t1 on t.id = t1.teamid

group by t.name
```

Result will look like this:

```
Name  Goals
H1    7
H2    2
H3    7
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa3cc/15
Although the example is for MySQL (because SQL Server Fiddle was acting up), the SQL statements will remain valid for SQL Server also.

Comment: @NicuHutu You are welcome. Feel free to wait for more concise answers from others, but do make sure that you accept one of the answers if they helped you

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without `unions`:

```
select t.id, t.name,
sum(case when oa.team1id = t.id then oa.team1score else 0 end +
    case when oa.team2id = t.id then oa.team2score else 0 end)
from team t
outer apply(select g.team1id, g.team2id, s.team1score, s.team2score 
            from game g 
            join score s on g.id = s.gameid
            where team1id = t.id or team2id = t.id) oa
group by t.id, t.name
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative:

```
select t.name,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN gt.teamSeq = 1 then s.team1Score
        WHEN gt.teamSeq = 2 then s.team2Score
    END) As Scores
from 
    team t 
    LEFT JOIN
    (select g.id,
        case 
            when g.team1id = t.id then g.team1id
            when g.team2id = t.id then g.team2id
        end as teamid,
        case 
            when g.team1id = t.id then 1
            when g.team2id = t.id then 2
        end as teamSeq
    from game g
        cross join
        team t) gt
    ON t.id = gt.teamid
    LEFT JOIN
    score s
    ON gt.id = s.gameid
where
    gt.teamid IS NOT NULL 
group by
    t.name
```